# Set tkinter filedialog to open only executable files

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Is there a way to set the tkinter filedialog `filetypes` attribute to open executable files?
I've been using:

```
filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Applications", "*.exe")],)
```

but it only opens .exe files, not all types of executable files (eg. .APP).
I could add more attributes to `filetypes`, but it will not work properly on Linux, where any file can be executed, as long as it has the execute permissions [(see here)](https://www.webhostinghero.com/which-are-the-linux-executable-files-and-how-do-we-create-them/).

**How can I set thinter's filedialog to only open any kind of executable file?**

I am using Python 3.6.4 on Windows 10 and Python 3.5 on Ubuntu 16.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing you can do by using the standard dialogs. Tkinter doesn't support listing files by attributes other than their extensions. You'll have to create your own file selection dialog if you want this feature.